# How to execute a binary file on a gcsfuse file system?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I am working in a bucket (gcsfuse) and I was explained that the command syntaxes are different on this type of file system.
I need to launch a `script.e` script but I can't find anywhere the command use to launch that type of script. I was hoping something simple like `bash script.e` would work but alas... (And obvioulsy I am very new to cloud storage).

What am I supposed to use? Also, is there somewhere a documentation or anything that lists the different commands that should be used in a gcsfuse file system?

Comment: What's the relation with Cloud Storage? The script.e file must be run with its interpretor, stored in GCS or not.

Comment: Well I'm not sure, again I'm very new to working with servers and cloud so it's a bit complicated for me to understand the differences that can exist. The interpreter you're talking about is stored somewhere that could be read on a server or is it something that has to be looked for somewhere else? Again, sorry if my question is dumb.

Comment: Show the script, someone might recognize the language it is written in. I have never seen a script with the file suffix `.e`. Also, do not use descriptions like `would not work`. Show what you did and the response.